# How to get distance and angle to an object using stereo cameras? (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I have seen a few different examples, but I am still unable to grasp how I can actually get the distance to a particular object.
Suppose I managed to successfully detect the center point  of an object for both the left camera(Yl,Yr) and right camera (Xl,Xr). I have obtained the camera parameters via stereo camera calibration.

I can calculate the disparity between two images, as shown in the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html).

I know the formulae is:

> Depth = Baseline * focal length/ Disparity

I know the baseline and focal length (1.8mm from spec shee), but not sure how to proceed from here to get what I want: **distance**

Edit: here is how I am calculating distance:
I know the FOV of the camera is 185 degrees.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
right_image = cv2.imread('right.jpg')

# get width of image
width = right.image.shape[1]

# calculate focal length in pixels
focal_length = (width*0.5)/np.tan(185*0.5*np.pi/180)

# obtained the center location of an object for both left and right # images. Only X values needed for disparity
object_center_left_x = 1060  # example
object_center_right_x = 1040 # example
disparity = object_center_left_x - object_center_right_x

# calculate depth/distance
distance = (baseline*focal_length)/disparity
print (distance)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, thanks! And please consider whether SO is the right plattform for this question.

Comment: Thank you, I have added code to show how I am calculating the distance.